# Converting words into Unicode

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone please explain this block of code to me? I don't really understand.

1. Why do I need to declare `uniMessage = ""` what is the use of it here? Sometimes when I code I realise that I need to declare it beforehand but sometimes I don't need to.
2. Why I need to use `+=` and also convert the user inputted word into `str`? Isn't `+=` is like `unicode = unicode + str(ord(char))`? I don't see the impact of `+=` here why can't I just use `=`. And if I thought that the user inputted message is already a string? Why do I need to convert it into `str` again?
3. Also it is not necessary to convert `convMessage += chr(int(alphabet))` into integer isn't it?

   ```
   message = input("Enter a word ")

   uniMessage = ""
   for char in message:
       uniMessage += str(ord(char))
   print("Unicode message:", uniMessage)

   convMessage = ""
   for i in range(0, len(uniMessage)-1, 2):
       alphabet = uniMessage[i] + uniMessage[i+1]
       convMessage += chr(int(alphabet))
   print("Orginal message:", convMessage)
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Important clarification**

The code is not a real Unicode encoding/decoding because is supposing that the Unicode characters you will input have just two decimal digits. You can test that yourself if you enter `def` as input, those characters have 100, 101 and 102 ASCII code.

**(1)**`uniMessage = ""` needed because you are using it the first time as a right part of an assignment operator.

```
uniMessage += str(ord(char))
```

is "equivalent" to:

```
uniMessage = uniMessage + str(ord(char))
```

and in Python a variable need to be declared before used and the `=` operator evaluate the right operant first.

**(2)** `+=` is just syntax sugar, so yes, you can use the `=`, but some people would say that is less pythonic and "harder" to read ;) I recommend to use `+=` when you can. You have to convert to string using `str` because you are before converting user input to a number using `ord`. [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)

**(3)** Is necessary because `uniMessage` is a string, a string full of digits characters, but still a string.

Comment: Why can't i just code `uniMessage = str(ord(char))` Since it was declared with no value? Shouldn't make any impact isnt it? That `uniMessage` in `uniMessage + str(ord(char))` doesnt seems to do anything?

Comment: You could write `uniMessage = str(ord(char))` for just one character input, but you are processing the user input that could be more than 1 character, that is why you put `uniMessage += str(ord(char))` inside a `for` loop. You need to add the code of each character to the "encoded" string, is like an accumulation, like a sum.

Answer (score 0):

That code might intend to convert characters into their internal number representation and back to a string. But that code just **fails** for 8-bit coded characters below line feed (typically 0x0A = 10dec) and above "c" (0x63 = 99dec). 
Besides that, in Python every string is a Unicode string with a UTF-8 encoding. Using other encoding is possible (`str.encode()`), however, will yield "bytes"